# Implement assert_called_once_with() method with default parameters

Tags: unit-testing, pytest, pytest-mock

```
def function(mocker):
   mock_search = mocker.patch.object(Class, "mock_function", return_value={})
   if Class.function("param1", "param2"):
        mock_search.assert_called_once_with("param1", "param2", url=default_url)
   elif Class.function("param1", "param2", url="URL"):
        mock_search.assert_called_once_with("param1", "param2", url="URL")
```

Is there a way to compact the code. It should execute such that if Class.function("param1", "param2", url="URL") has url passed in Class.function method, the assert_called_once_with should be executed with the passed URL (if not) execute with default url.

Comment: ideally you shouldn't put logic in tests -- DRY is *bad* for readability and maintainability.  tests should be obvious to read and write

Comment: That is one reason for me to write the function without "if" statement.

Comment: don't do that, have two functions or better yet just inline your assertion